# QGIS Plugin - How to import external libraries

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attributeerror, osmnx, scikit-learn

I'm developing a plugin for **QGIS** that uses *external libraries* such as **OSMnx**, **Shapely**, and **Scikit-learn**. In particular, the last one is an *optional dependency* of OSMnx.

At first I created a lib folder with all the **.whl** file inside. Only the scikit-learn library is causing me problems with the following error:

[image: Impossible find the specified path:]

The .whl was present but I didn't understand why it tried to access it as if it was a folder.

Then I tried to force the installation of these libs using the following code:

```py
def import_libs():
    libs = [
        ['osmnx', 'osmnx', '1.8.0'],
        ['shapely', 'shapely', '2.0.2'],
        ['scikit-learn', 'sklearn.neighbors', '1.3.2']
    ]

    for lib, import_name, version in libs:
        try:
            __import__(import_name)
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            print(f'Module {lib} not found. Installing...')
            from pip._internal import main as pip
            pip(['install', "--ignore-installed", f"{lib}=={version}"])
            __import__(import_name)
```

But this error was thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/Beolo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Interoperability\utils.py", line 86, in import_libs
    __import__(import_name)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/Beolo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Interoperability\__init__.py", line 36, in classFactory
    import_libs()
  File "C:\Users/Beolo/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Interoperability\utils.py", line 90, in import_libs
    pip(['install', "--ignore-installed", f"{lib}=={version}"])
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in main
    return _wrapper(args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\entrypoints.py", line 35, in _wrapper
    sys.stderr.write(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

It seems that the error caught is empty and cannot use the write function.

Can anyone help me to deal with these external libraries?

Comment: Don't do this if this plugin is going to be publicly available. Not everyone uses the basic QGIS Windows installer, there are many ways to install QGIS and `pip install` is a poor choice for some installs, particularly conda envs and linux and you can trash these.

Comment: So what can I use to import these libraries? I tried to force the pip install only because was my last idea but I know that is a poor choice

Comment: Hi, just document your recommended ways to install those libraries in the qgis environment and let the users install them in their machines.